# How to get sp_send_dbmail to format the body that is sourced from a table

Tags: sql

I'm using sp-send_dbmail to send an email. I populate the @body content by selecting from a table where the column is defined as text. The actual content of the email is stored in the tables column.

How do I get the email to show the line breaks and format accordingly? I tried the format as HTML and TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

Try and make sure that the `body_format` property is set to `HTML`.

> [ @body_format= ] 'body_format'
>
> ```
> Is the format of the message body. The parameter is of type varchar(20), 
> with a default of NULL. When specified, the headers of the outgoing message 
> are set to indicate that the message body has the specified format. The 
> parameter may contain one of the following values:
>
>     TEXT
>
>     HTML
>
> Defaults to TEXT.
> ```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx